# How do I make Jukebox music that follows a player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Believe it or not, there are still players that listen to music discs in Minecraft, including me.

I tried making a command loop that would play different discs for me every 5 minutes. Here's what command I use:

```
/execute at Quijibo run playsound minecraft:music_disc.stal record Quijibo
```

This successfully executes the command, and the music starts playing, but if I move away from the point where I was standing, the music fades away, as if there was a jukebox playing the music that I'm moving away from.

What I want to do is have the music follow me when moving. Is this possible to do through commands?

Comment: Unlikely, at least without restarting the track every time.

Comment: Yeah, but even if I would be playing the track using continuous commands, I don't know how I would keep the music going without pausing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory the `minimumVolume` parameter should fulfil exactly this purpose, but I couldn't get it to work. Maybe that's a bug.

But the `volume` parameter of `/playsound` can in a way actually be used to specify a spatial volume instead of an audio volume! The trick, as described in the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/playsound) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Commands/playsound&oldid=1387461)):

> For values greater than 1.0, the sound will not actually grow louder, but its audible range (a 16-block radius at 1.0) will be multiplied by volume. There will always be a gradual falloff to silence based on distance from the center of the sphere.

That means that you can just enter the maximum value of a `Float`, except that it's for some reason slightly different in Minecraft. By just trying out values I found that the maximum value is:

```
340282356779733661637539395458142568447.99999…
```

So you can use this command to play a sound everywhere:

```
/playsound <sound> <channel> <selector> <x> <y> <z> 340282356779733661637539395458142568447.9999999999
```

That way it only gets 0.000000000000000000000000000024936% quieter when you go to the other end of the world.

This even works across dimensions for some reason. But when you go through a portal, the sound stops.

Comment: But to be clear there is no way to make a playsound follow a player without expanding the distance it can be heard?

Comment: Dammit! Now every time I walk away 12,033,694,344,163,658,243,080,625,752,106,000,000 blocks away from the source, I won't be able to hear the music. I hate it when that happens!

Comment: @Nik3141 No, `/playsound` always has a point of origin of the sound, just like almost all sounds in Minecraft. The exceptions (dragon death, wither summoning) actually also apply to `/playsound`, no matter the origin and radius. I didn't test what happens with the background music. But since `/playsound` lets you select who hears a sound, that doesn't matter anyway, you can just select players who are in a radius initially, if you want that.

Comment: @Fabian I was hoping I could play the sound at the location of an entity or something moving rather than fixed coords. Essentially, I didn't want to restrict who could hear it in any way other than their distance from a particular entity (player).

Comment: @Nik3141 Then just use the coordinates of that entity, `@a` and the radius you want.

Comment: But those coordinates are fixed. If I, a player, am the source of a sound, and fall off a cliff, that sound won't fade away to any observing players at the top of the cliff: it'll stay fixed in place. I was just wondering if you could somehow use a changing/moving position to be the origin point of a sound, but it appears that you can't.

Comment: Oh, you want to be the source of the sound and have that move around, audible for other players. They no, the sound system of Minecraft doesn't allow that. And they didn't even write that themselves, so it's unlikely that that changes anytime soon. Your best option would be to cut the sound up into many small pieces. Or, if the path and duration of movement is known, you can do something like Noxcrew did in the "Terra swoop force" map for their elevator, they have a video about it on their YouTube channel.