# What is causing some custom sounds to not follow the player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-resource-packs

I'm working on an adventure map in Java Minecraft that requires sounds to be played to the player. These sounds should follow the player around such that the origin of the sound is the player themselves. I achieve this using the command:

```
/execute at @r run playsound minecraft:demo.demointro master @a ~ ~ ~ 1
```

This works properly. The `sounds.json` file located inside the resource pack's `assets/minecraft` folder has listed the sound, demointro like so:

```
},
    "demo.demointro": {
        "category": "master",
        "sounds": [
            {
                "name": "demo/demointro",
                "stream": true
        }]
```

I have another sound which I also wish to have play in a similar manner. It's called "28". The command I am using to play this sound appears like this:

```
/execute at @r run playsound minecraft:demo.28 master @a ~ ~ ~ 1
```

and inside of the sounds.json file, it is structured like this:

```
},
    "demo.28": {
        "category": "master",
        "sounds": [
            {
                "name": "demo/28",
                "stream": true

            }]
```

However, when the command to play this sound is run, it only plays within the radius of the given coordinates (in the case of this command, it would be ~ ~ ~) instead of wherever the player goes. What is going on here, and why is this not working the way I feel it should?

I've recorded a short video which demonstrates my problem in action:

Comment: I had the same problem and [asked the same question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/352299/how-do-i-make-jukebox-music-that-follows-a-player). Does it solve your problem?