# Is there any way to make it so you hear a music disc anywhere?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Is there any way I can make it so I can hear a music disc anywhere, without it fading away if I'm far away?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make Jukebox music that follows a player?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/352299/how-do-i-make-jukebox-music-that-follows-a-player)

Comment: @OKprogrammer Not a duplicate. This is a bedrock edition question and that is a java edition question.

Comment: The simplest way would be to use /playsound command, or download a pre-existing resource pack that increases the range of a jukebox. Alternatively, you can go into the game files and change the fade distance yourself, but that's a little more difficult and might break things.

Answer (score 1):

What you'll need is to turn on cheats, and then head into the chat.

Then , type in this command:

```
/playsound record.pigstep @s
```

Instead of pigstep, you can use these music discs:

- record.11
- record.13
- record.blocks
- record.cat
- record.chirp
- record.far
- record.mall
- record.mellohi
- record.pigstep
- record.stal
- record.strad
- record.wait
- record.ward

Lets say, if I wanted to play the music disc "Chirp", I would type in

```
/playsound record.chirp @s
```

Note that instead of writing `@s` means the person executing the command, so you. If you want it to play to everyone currently online in the world, you can use `@a` instead (or any other valid player selectors).

Comment: I changed it from the name to @s so that way it's simpler (no need to change anything) and added a bit about @a just in case they get confused if other people can't hear it, just letting you know since this was a somewhat large change

Comment: Ok, that makes a lot more sense. Thanks!